# Вставка видео на сайт

Tags: html5, видео

Здравствуйте, как можно вставить видео на сайт (как элемент дизайна) в формате скажем mp4 1024 так, чтоб оно имело только одну кнопку звука и было зацикленно?

Answer (score 1):

[Посмотрите здесь](http://www.coolwebmasters.com/video/708-21-free-video-players-for-your-website.html)

http://htmlbook.ru/html5/video

```
<video controls autoplay>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; />   
</video>
```

Comment: это не то, это плееры, в моем случае видео должно идти в шаблоне сайта, как элемент дизайна